# How to attach files from mobile phone to SharePoint list Item with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to upload/attach files from mobile devices to a SharePoint list item. I can upload files from computers but it doesn't work if I do it from my smartphone. Here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                url: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Random_List')/items(${id})/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='${fileName}')`,
                method: 'POST',
                async: false,
                binaryStringRequestBody: true,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                    'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                    'X-RequestDigest': data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
                },
                data: buffer,
                success: function() {
                    alert("Success")
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    alert('DID NOT ATTACH FILE: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @UBK I actually don't get any errors and it goes to the success function but nothing is uploaded/attached. This only happens on mobile devices and not on computers.